# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ApplicationUser_xxxxxxxx' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to save the data into database using below `ActionResult`

```
public ActionResult Create(GigFormViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var artistId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var artist = _context.Users.Single(u => u.Id == artistId);
        var genre = _context.Genres.Single(g => g.Id == viewModel.Genre);
        var gig = new Gig
        {
            Artist = artist,
            DateTime = DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0} {1}", viewModel.Date, viewModel.Time)),
            Genre=genre,
            Venue=viewModel.Venue
        };
        _context.Gigs.Add(gig);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

    }
```

While Saving the data, I am getting error

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ApplicationUser_C811B05818B5E64ECDA3F7F75CC04ED97BE32CA9226F31FEEEF1EE499B74428B' to type 'System.String'.

Below is the screenshot for  more details:
[image]

Models:

```
public class Genre
{
    public byte Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Gig
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public ApplicationUser Artist { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Venue { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Genre Genre { get; set; }
}
```

What could be the issue??

Comment: Show the definition of `Gig`, `Artist`, `Venue` and `Genre`

Comment: And publish call stack at the exception point :)

Comment: @haim770 I have added my Model classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out myself.
I think it was issue with Gigs Model and validation of `Artist`.
Removed Data Annotation `[StringLength(255)]` and it worked fine.

So updated Gigs Model class is as below:

```
public class Gig
 {
public int Id { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(255)]
public ApplicationUser Artist { get; set; }

[Required]
public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

[Required]
public string Venue { get; set; }

[Required]
public Genre Genre { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this exact same error was due to the DateTime object not recognizing the way I had formatted the string passed to it.

I input the time as '9.05' (using a period) whereas DateTime expects a colon '9:05'.

Mosh did mention in the video that he assumes valid input, and that validation will be added later. So to get over this hurdle make sure your test data is valid for [DateTime String Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx)